# SailsJS secure authentication

Tags: authentication, sails.js

I am building app using SailsJS as backend and angular as frontend. On many websites I have found that auth is done by setting `req.session.userID` to som value but then in policy it only performs basic check like `if(req.session.userID)` but I am not sure that this is secure. What if I put some random string to my cookie named `userID` will system consider this as valid login?

For example my correct `userID` is `ABCDEF` but what if some attacker come by and he sets his cookie userID to `DEFGH`. Will system consider this as valid login? I don't think that there is some background validation against database going on. Wouldn't it be better to create model called Sessions which will store randomly generated session ID and associated userID? Then the system at user login would generate random sessionID which will be stored in DB and in policy system will check if currently set `req.session.sessionID` is valid.

I am asking this because I don't have very deep understanding of sails but from my point of view solution proposed in documentation doesn't seem secure.

Comment: Which documentation in particular? Can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you take a look at [JWT](https://jwt.io/) and how it solves some problems. Then another problem will be "how to store this token". And that you can solve with cookies, local storage, etc. all depending on your needs and possibilities. Usually a `local storage` + `middleware` in the client side with `reddis` on the server side (advanced session behavior) is enough.